# How to use WordNet in a C project?

Tags: c, wordnet

I'm trying to link to WordNet library. I downloaded the header file (wn.h), libWN.a file and a bunch of .o files (libWN_a-search.o, etc) from [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/download/current-version). I put a main.c, wn.h and libWN.a files in a folder and implemented main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "wn.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char rc, *s; 

  s = "cat";
  rc = in_wn(s, ALL_POS);
  printf("rc: %d\n", rc);
  return 0;
}
```

I try to compile using `cc main.c -L.` but I get the linker error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvzqY4x.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `in_wn'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Documentation on WordNet lib can be found [here](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/documentation/wnintro3wn). I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including the `wn.h` header file is not enough. The .h file only contains the *declarations*, but the actual implemenation is contained in the library file `libWN.a` which you failed to link with.

For linking with that library you need to tell the compiler to do so by adding `-lWN`:

```
cc main.c -L. -lWN
```